# Let A and B be two subsets of some universal set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Let A and B be two subsets of some universal set.
Prove that if $(A\cup B)^c$ = $A^c$ U $B^c$, then A = B.**

ATTEMPT:

Let $x$ ∈ $(A\cup B)^c$

Then, $x$ ∈ ($A^c\cap B^c$)

$x$∈$A^c$ and $x$∈$B^c$

$x$∉A and $x$∉B

$x$∉(A$\cap$B)

Now, let $x$∈($A^c\cup B^c$)

Then, $x$∈$A^c$ OR  $x$∈$B^c$

$x$∉$A$ OR $x$∉$B$

$x$∉($A\cup B$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to show that $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$; this makes no sense, since the problem is to show that **if** $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$, then $A=B$. In other words, you should be simply assuming as a given that $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$ and trying to use that to show that $A=B$. I’ll get you started on the right track. Assume that $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$.

Let $x\in A$. Then $x\in A\cup B$, so $x\notin(A\cup B)^c$. By hypothesis $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$, so $x\notin A^c\cup B^c$. In particular, then, $x\notin B^c$, and therefore $x\in B$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $A$, this shows that $A\subseteq B$.

To finish it off, you need to show that $B\subseteq A$; a similar argument will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of DeMorgan's Laws: $(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c$.

Then we have $(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c = A^c \cup B^c$. If the union and intersections of two sets are equal, then there does not exist an element in the union of the sets that is not in their intersection, so neither set contains an element that is not contained by the other set, so the two sets are equal: $A^c = B^c$. Take the complement of both: $A = B$.